# Difference between Multiview control and AjaxToolkit Tabs

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Is there a major difference between the Multiview control in ASP.NET 2.0 and the Tab control in the AjaxToolkit?

Other than the built in visuals of the tab control, is there anything different in the way they handle the hiding/showing of controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a big difference. The Ajax tab control will do all tab switching client side, which means there is no postback/callback when switching tabs. The traditional tab control makes a postback every time you switch.

This means that the ActiveTabChanged event won't fire, unless you set AutoPostBack to true. There is an event called ClientActiveTabChanged that fires in javascript, though, so you could use that instead of forcing a postback.

Answer (score 0):

So what is the difference between a commercial tab control let say from DevExpress and making one with Fireworks that is Javascript based.